# Using the completion function for a command that is passed as an argument to another command

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion, command

Is it possible to programmatically get a command's definition so that its completion function can be called manually?  Alternatively, is it possible to define a command such that the first argument is used to determine the completion function to use?

### What I'm trying to do:

I have some commands (`Cmd1`, `Cmd2`, etc.) that are defined with their own completion function using the `-complete` flag.  The completion function might be a custom function or may be one of the built in options like `file` or `shellcmd`.

I'm now creating a "wrapper command" (`WrapperCmd`) that would take in a command name and that command's arguments.  So, invoking things would be something like this:

`:WrapperCmd Cmd1 cmd1-argument`

After typing `:WrapperCmd Cmd1`  the completion options should be the ones relevant to `Cmd1` and after typing `:WrapperCmd Cmd2`  the completion options should be the ones relevant to `Cmd2`.

### P.S.

I really struggled to come up with a clear and succinct way of phrasing the title (perhaps an indication that I'm trying to get too weird with things).  Suggestions for improving it are more than welcome.

Comment: Assuming you have some logic for `WrapperCmd`'s `-complete=function` to examine current arguments, have a look at `getcompletion()`

Comment: Some very brief testing seems to suggest this is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks!  If you care to turn this into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted once I get things working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light on details, but: you can call `getcompletion()` to find out how Vim would complete for certain strings. So if you can examine the command line and pass sensible values to `getcompletion()` in `WrapperCmd`'s completion function, you're probably in buisinesss.